# Angular 5 Date time zone differences between pc and mobile

Tags: datetime, mobile, safari, timezone, angular5

I am listing date in my website. On pc it is showing;

```
2018-04-14T14:00:00
```

But on mobile (safari), it is;

```
2018-04-14T17:00:00
```

It is adding +3.

But on mobile (chrome) it works right.

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: we are talking about ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not angular specific, but apple specific.
there seems to be some issues with timezones in some applications in osx and ios. Try to reset your date and time to default (restore defaults).